# If a function $f$ is is differentiable and oscillatory, then is its derivative $f'$ also oscillatory?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I know this is true but I'm trying to figure out a proof for it.

To clarify what oscillatory means:

*Oscillatory* means that a function $f$ has an unbounded set of roots.

Comment: Rolle's theorem?